# How to join on dynamic tables from a main table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Basically we have this concept:

**Main table:**

vehicles

```
id|name|created_by|type|created_at
```

**vehicle field data**

truck_fields

```
vehicle_id|door_count|height|max_load|truck_size
```

car_fields

```
vehicle_id|doors|max_passengers|engine_size
```

motorbike_fields

```
vehicle_id|wheel_count|max_weight
```

aero_plane_fields

```
vehicle_id|window_count|engine_power
```

aero_plane_fields

```
vehicle_id|window_count|engine_power
```

etc....

Basically this is a contrived example which demonstrates our structure. We have a table of vehicles and n number of `*_fields` tables where we store properties about each of these vehicles based on the type. We know these field tables and type mappings at dev time but are struggling in a way to write a query that would allows us to essentially lets say, paginate the list of vehicles WITH each rows associated fields.

so e.g.

```
SELECT v.*, row_to_json(d) from vehicles JOIN truck_fields d on d.vehicle_id = v.id
UNION ALL
SELECT v.*, row_to_json(d) from vehicles JOIN car_fields d on d.vehicle_id = v.id
UNION ALL
SELECT v.*, row_to_json(d) from vehicles JOIN motorbike_fields d on d.vehicle_id = v.id
UNION ALL
SELECT v.*, row_to_json(d) from vehicles JOIN areoplane_fields d on d.vehicle_id = v.id
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10
```

This is obviously extremely inefficient query so looking for help in a potentially either)

a. alternative structure that would better facilitate this query

b. a better query that would achieve this same outcome

We've tried alternatives like EAV structure but obviously this is quite a big anti-patten.